# CAtlHttpClient - Navigate to an IP6 address seems not to work

Tags: c++, http, atl, ipv6

I'm using the ATL Server CAtlHttpCLient to send HTTP requests to a server.

Basically my code looks like this:

```
ATL::CAtlHttpClient client;
ATL::CAtlNavigateData navigateData;
navigateData.SetSocketTimeout(60000);
navigateData.SetMethod(ATL_HTTP_METHOD_POST);
BX_TString jmfmime = "application/vnd.cip4-jmf+xml";
navigateData.SetPostData((BYTE*) msg.c_str(), msg.length(), jmfmime.c_str());

client.Navigate("http://[fe80::21a:a0ff:fec1:5917%6]:8090/someextrastuff", &navigateData);
```

When I use an IP4 address to connect everything works like the best.  However the Navigate function does not seem to work for IP6 addresses.

Internally the '[' and ']' characters are not considered as valid characters in an URL and the URL is converted to something like this `http://%5bfe80::21a:a0ff:fec1:5917%6%5d:8090/someextrastuff`.  As a result the URL can not be parsed.

I understood that CAtlHttpClient should support both IP4 and IP6 adresses.  So it seems that I'm missing something.

Should I specify the IP6 address in a different way?

Or I'm not allowed to specify an IP address in the Navigate function and should I always use the host name and hope that the client is always able to resolve the host name?

Answer (score 1):

In my version of ATL (included with Visual Studio 2005), the URL is parsed with the CUrl helper class; that class doesn't appear to support IPv6 addresses.  Perhaps this is fixed in more recent versions?  If not, you could manually build a CUrl object and pass it to the overloaded Navigate() method.